# How to reset image file preview after ajax success in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax and PHP PDO to insert into the database. I have two fields. 1. Message and 2. image. I have an issue, the image preview(browse file ) is not resetting after data inserted and display (After ajax success). The message Textarea value is resetting but not image preview after ajax success.

Ajax code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#save", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('message', message)
    var property = document.getElementById('photo').files;
    property = property[0];
    if (property) {
        var image_name = property.name;
        var image_extension = image_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        form_data.append("file", property);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_posts.php",
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //Insert data before the message wrap div
            $(data).insertBefore(".message-wrap:first");
            //Clear the textarea message
            $("#message").val("");

            $("#form")[0].reset();
            $('#preview').attr('src', "#");
            $("#photo").val("");


        }
    });
});
```

I am using JS to preview image on change (browse image and see preview )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Image Preview Function
    $("#uploadTrigger").click(function(){
       $("#photo").click();
    });
          function readURL(input) {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();
   
                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#body-bottom').show();
                      $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                                $("#photo").val("");
                  }
   
                  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
          }
   
</script>
```

The message value is resetting after inserted but not the image.
I am using an HTML code line to preview.

```
<div id="body-bottom"> 
   <img src="#"  id="preview"/> 
</div>
```

The image preview should be reset and also type="file "
I am using type file code:

```
<input type="file"  onchange="readURL(this);" style="display:none;" name="photo" id="photo">
<img src="assets/icon/icon1.png"></img><a href="#" id="uploadTrigger" name="post_image">Add Photo</a>
```

The image preview is not resetting. If I click again the same image inserts. I want to reset the image after ajax success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Just add line above the form reset

$("#photo").val("");
$("#form")[0].reset();

Or you can place form reset at the end .
If you want to hide preview then add line -

$('#body-bottom').hide();